# Unable to detect Digital Persona 5100 Device using Android Phone

Tags: android, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I want to build an Attendance based Android application though the fingerprint using `Digital Persona 5100` fingerprint reader. I know it is possible to build android application using this device but I am unable to find `Digital Persona 5100` Android SDK and also unable to find the proper documentation to build android Application using `Persona 5100`. I just want to get the image of fingerprint by persona device. Any help will be appreciable.

I implement in gradle as I find to detect persona Device but it is not working with my device:

> Error : No device Detect

Comment: repositories {
                maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/shodgson/uareu4500reader' }
            }

Comment: implementation 'asia.kanopi.tools:fingerscan:0.1'

Comment: Is your Android device support USB OTG ? What's the result of 'lsusb' in adb shell before and after plug ?

Comment: No actually I am using the normal android device which does not support USB OTG. Sorry For late Reply.

Comment: @kirti how to use 'asia.kanopi.tools:fingerscan:0.1' I cannot find any method.